# Image to an excel spreadsheet in R

Tags: r, excel, image

I have this script so I can convert an image to an excel. However, when I save to Excel, it is saved empty, without the printed image. Do you know why that happens?

Underneath, the libraries are loaded and the code is initialized.

```
library(raster)
library(openxlsx)
library(magick)
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
require(lazyeval)
[enter image description here][1]
img <- readJPEG("hSAxgtiSnG.jpg", native = TRUE)

rlogo <- image_read(img) %>% 
  image_scale("50%") %>%
  image_data()

size  <- dim(rlogo[1,,])
rlogo <- as.raster(as.integer(rlogo)/255)
plot(rlogo)

rlogo <- as.character(rlogo)
dim(rlogo) <- size 
rlogo <- as.data.frame(rlogo)

colours <- rlogo %>% 
  gather(col, colour) %>%
  group_by(col) %>%
  mutate(row = seq(n())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(col = readr::parse_number(col))

blank <- rlogo
blank[] <- ""

wb <- createWorkbook("coolbutuseless")
addWorksheet(wb, "Rlogo", gridLines = TRUE)
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, blank, colNames = FALSE)
setColWidths(wb, shee=1, cols=seq(size[1]), widths = 2)

for (col_df in split(colours, colours$colour)) {
  cell_style <- createStyle(col_df$colour[[1]])
  addStyle(wb, sheet = 1, cell_style, rows = col_df$col, cols = col_df$row, gridExpand = FALSE)
}

openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, "crap_2.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this idea. I've thought about doing it myself but never got round to implementing it, so thanks for posting your code. It only needed a couple of tweaks to get it working, and it works very well.

Your problem is that you are passing your colour strings as an unnamed parameter to `createStyle()` so they are being interpreted as inputs to the first parameter, which is the font style. In effect, it thinks you want the cells to have fonts called "#FFFFFFFF" etc. You need to specify `createStyle(fgFill = col_df$colour)`. Actually, you also need to ensure that the colour strings have only 6 hex characters, by removing the final "FF" on each string, otherwise it will throw, so it should be

`cell_style <- createStyle(fgFill = substr(col_df$colour[[1]], 1, 7))`.

Here is the full working code:

```r
library(raster)
library(openxlsx)
library(magick)
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
require(lazyeval)
require(jpeg)      # NB also need the jpeg package for readJPEG

# I grabbed the jpeg from your post and saved it in my default directory
img <- readJPEG(path.expand("~/lg3vn.jpg"), native = TRUE)

rlogo <- image_read(img)    %>%
         image_scale("50%") %>%
         image_data()

size  <- dim(rlogo[1,,])
rlogo <- as.raster(as.integer(rlogo)/255)
plot(rlogo)

rlogo <- as.character(rlogo)
dim(rlogo) <- size
rlogo <- as.data.frame(rlogo)

colours <- rlogo         %>%
  gather(col, colour)    %>%
  group_by(col)          %>%
  mutate(row = seq(n())) %>%
  ungroup()              %>%
  mutate(col = readr::parse_number(col))

blank   <- rlogo
blank[] <- ""

wb <- createWorkbook("coolbutuseless")
addWorksheet(wb, "Rlogo", gridLines = TRUE)
writeData(wb, "Rlogo", blank, colNames = FALSE)
setColWidths(wb, "Rlogo", cols = seq(size[1]), widths = 2)

for (col_df in split(colours, colours$colour)) 
{
  cell_style <- createStyle(fgFill = substr(col_df$colour[[1]], 1, 7))
  addStyle(wb, "Rlogo", cell_style, rows = col_df$col, cols = col_df$row)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, path.expand("~/crap_2.xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

Here's a successful screenshot. Nice.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Well done, I'm glad I could help you too. Greetings and happy new year!

Comment: Thank you. You have also turned a noob into an established user by tipping me over 1000 rep!